# What is a reasonable level of security between my iOS app and my API

Tags: ios, security, oauth, afnetworking

I'm currently working on getting up to speed on security between the iOS app I've written and the PHP API I've written.

Parameters that seem important:
- I'm using AFNetworking
- I'm already using HTTPS
- I'm already using Certs from the hosting company

This is a chat/messaging app. No billing. No data that needs extra precautions. Just username and password.

I'm trying to determine what reasonable due diligence is for an iOS app.

I've beed reading about oAuth 1a (many seem to not like oAuth2?)

The "consumer" client portion of the oAuth experience (while using AFNetworking) seems to involve a trip to the web browser and back to the app via custom URL protocol. That seems like HORRIBLE UX to me.

I know I can't control which client is accessing my API. 
I'm aware that there are limitations and that there are no perfect solutions.

I'm just trying to find, at a higher level, what's "best practice"? What's acceptable in the sense that someone else looking at your app would think, "that seems reasonable."

I know SO doesn't always deal well with open-ended subjective questions like this, but it really is what I'm looking for. What's the general consensus?

And if this isn't something that can be answered here, can someone point me to a better place to look for the answer? Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing about security is to put it in context: "Secure from what attacks, motivated by what, at what cost?"

- HTTPS: foils passive snoopers. Cost: minimal.
- HTTPS with certificate validation: foils trivial active interceptors. Cost: minor.
- HTTPS with certificate pinning: foils active interceptors who can't impersonate your cert vendor. Cost: a little involved.

Bonus points: use a certificate or cipher in the security that has ephemeral keys -- this means that even if someone gets your server's keys later, they can't go back and read what's already been said if they have a recording.

"Chat" can be highly valuable to intercept -- especially in nations where spying on users is the norm. Doubly so group chat. Chat is definitely not the base, 'valueless data' case. There's a wealth of valuable data and metadata in there.

OAuth1 and OAuth2 are authorization frameworks: They help describe and systematize *who has access to what*. That's it. It's useful only in a three-party system: When the group delegating who has access is separate from the one requesting or allowing it. The whole "authorize this app to post on my account" button is the canonical feature. OAuth1 does it with tokens and cryptography and kinda sucks to implement but is pretty solid. OAuth2 is just a stinky hot potato that isn't an interoperable standard and whose steward in the standards process has disavowed.

The hard analytic work is 'secure from who, with what motivation?' -- there's all kinds of attacks from simple spam and misuse to active denial of service, active attempts to break into servers, and active attempts to intercept communication.

Username, if it's shown publicly anyway, is mostly a privacy concern -- "how widely would someone want to be known as a user?" and perhaps who they are connected to if there's a social aspect to this application.

Passwords are attacked a number of ways.

- Brute force: stupid passwords will be guessed.
- Server break-in: If you don't store passwords hashed and salted in the server, someone who gets the list has those passwords trivially, and doesn't even have to crack them. I guarantee that users will use the same password for you and their bank. It happens.
- Password reset attacks -- security questions are rarely as secure as the password. Emails can be spoofed. Password reset systems often leave a token that can be used to reset exposed. Be careful.

These are just things that pop in off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense. Sounds like the implementing oAuth1a is a good idea then. I would feel comfortable with that. I just have to figure out how to not have the completely toxic UI experience from the browser trip. Also, there's tons of info on consuming services using oAuth, but not as much about creating a web service with oAuth.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: "The hard analytic work is 'secure from who, with what motivation?'" Also the total cost of a security failure, monetary and reputation. Assign a monetary value and you will have a good metric.